# How to find an element div in webpage which is named nav-submit-button with xpath?

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my selenium test, I need to find an button element with class name `nav-submit-button`.
I am writing following `xpath`

```
"//class='nav-submit-button nav-sprite']"
```

But its not working. can anybody tell me how to write a correct `xpath` to find a div with named `nav-submit-button`.

Comment: nav-submit-button is a class or a name?

Comment: "div class="nav-submit-button nav-sprite" its a div with a class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'nav-submit-button')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few bits...

```
//[@class="nab-submit-button"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression matches any `div` with a `class` attribute which contains a class name *that exactly matches* the string `nav-submit-button`:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' nav-submit-button ')]
```

In the example below, it will select the second, fourth and fifth nodes:

```
<div>
    <div class="nav-submit-button-1 nav-submit"></div>
    <div class="nav-submit-button"></div> <!-- Will select this -->
    <div class="a-class nav-submit-button-gremlin other-class"></div>
    <div class="nav nav-submit-button nav-other"></div> <!-- Will select this -->
    <div class="nav-submit-button nav-other"></div> <!-- Will select this -->
</div>
```

It won't match `nav-submit-button-gremlin` or `nav-submit-button-1` since they are not exact matches. Using `contains()` without concatenating spaces before and after the strings you are testing won't guarantee that.